# PayPal Checkout update cart totals dynamically after ajax

Tags: ajax, paypal, checkout

I have a shopping site which I'm converting to Ajax. It has a list of cart items.

On page load the PayPal button is set up correctly with the cart totals passed in.  However, now that I have an Ajax cart I need to update the cart totals when the cart changes.

If I call the paypal.Button.render  function again I get another button.

So I need to either delete the old button and rebuild or call something to update the totals.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is my code that sets up the button.

```
function PayPalButton(authResult) {

   // console.log(authResult);

    // Render the PayPal button
    paypal.Button.render({

        // Set your environment
        env: authResult.PayPalEnvironment, // sandbox | production

        // Specify the style of the button
        style: {
            label: 'generic',
            size: 'responsive',    // small | medium | large | responsive
            shape: 'rect',     // pill | rect
            color: 'blue',     // gold | blue | silver | black
            tagline: false
        },

        // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
        // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create

        client: {
            sandbox: authResult.PayPalClientId,
            production: authResult.PayPalClientId
        },

        payment: function (data, actions) {
            // recover transaction value here

            var carttotal = authResult.cart.FTotal - (authResult.VATApplies ? 0 : authResult.cart.VAT);
            var paymentGuid = authResult.cart.PaymentGuid;

            //alert(paymentGuid);

            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [{
                        amount: {
                                    total: carttotal.toString(), currency: 'GBP'
                                },
                        custom: paymentGuid.toString()
                        }]
                }
            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {

            return actions.payment.get().then(function (data) {

                return actions.payment.execute().then(function () {
                    processPayPal(data);
                });
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button-container');

};
```

Comment: I can't seem to find any easy way to refresh the button. Perhaps the only way is to crudely remove the all the stuff PP bungs into the dom with Jquery and then re-instate it?

Answer (score 0):

Well this works but it's ugly. Surely there must be a better way.

After updating the cart. I remove the PayButton button from the DOM and put the HTML back how it was. Then I call the routine to reconfigure the button.

```
$("#PayPalSection").remove();
$("#paypalButtonContainer").append('<div id="PayPalSection"><div class= "col-8 offset-2"><div id="paypal-button-container"></div></div></div>');
ConfigurePayPalButton();
```

This does a round trip to the DB unfortunately but I will try and write something that doesn't require that step.